# redux "undefined" when trying to get the data

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

im trying to read some data from Redux store but I keep getting undefined
this is based on redux template created using:
create-react-app [appname] --template redux

I know there most be an issue in how I read the data

this is my store:

```html
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import calculatorReducer from "../features/Data_calculator_slice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    calculator: calculatorReducer,
  },
});
```

my actions and initialState:

```html
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
const initialState = {
  value: [{ name: "test", wight: 18, grade: 12, gpa: "A" }],
};

export const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: "data",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    incrementByAmount: (state, action) => {
      state.value += action.payload;
      const currentValue = selectCount();
      console.log(currentValue);
    },
  },
});

export const { incrementByAmount } = counterSlice.actions;

export const selectCount = (state) => state.calculator.data;

/* export const selectCount = (state) => state.counter.value;
 */
export default counterSlice.reducer;
```

but here when I'm trying to fetch the data using the code below  it returns undefined

```html
 const count = useSelector(selectCount);
  console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the same selector in your reducers as you do in your component. One is scoped to the slice you're defining, the other is global. Also in your reducer you aren't passing the state to the `selectCount` selector so it can't return anything from the state.

in your reducer the selector for your value is `(state) => state.value`

in your component the selector for your value is `(state) => state.calculator.value`